# Gnome python bindings

Tags: python, gtk3, gnome-3

I am porting a PyGTK/Gnome application.

It uses `gnome` in a couple of places:

```
import gnome
gnome.program_init("prog", str(app_version), properties=props)
...
gnome.help_display("prog")
```

Searching the [gi reference](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) I cannot find such methods in any of the bindings...

There are three Gnome* bindings, but neither seems to offer these methods.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an old binding with `libgnome`, which was deprecated a long time ago in C.  I suggest you look for calls to gnome methods (like the gnome.help_display), and then look in Gtk3 for similar methods.

In the particular case of `gnome.help_display`, there is no equivalent for the old gnome help system in `Gtk3`. I suspect this is because modern systems are more HTML (or XML) oriented. Probably the best would be to base your new help system directly Python browser widget such as [`webkit`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonWebKit) (which can be embedded) instead of `libgnome`. You can also interface with your preferred browser with the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module. The code to embed `webkit` is fairly compact (see [`A browser in 14 lines`](https://ardoris.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/a-browser-in-14-lines-using-python-and-webkit/), or [`A minimal Gtk+/Webkit based browser`](https://gist.github.com/kklimonda/890640))

You also might want to look at the [`Python Sphinx`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) documentation system, which 'feels' nicer to me than `yelp`. It also generates [beautiful PDFs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/sphinx/stable/sphinx.pdf) from the LaTeX it produces.

Comment: I think I will just use `os.system('yelp myhelp.xml')` then. Thanks!

Comment: Added a note on Sphinx to the answer

Comment: Plus 1 for the mention of `webbrowser` it is effortless to use and picks your selected program based on the file type.

Comment: The problem is that the documentation is in DocBook format. The application integrates well with Gnome and is part of the Ubuntu main repository. I would prefer to keep it a DocBook, and avoid HTML. I will just call `yelp` directly for the time being.